# Django passing an argument from method to method

Tags: django, django-views

The problem is that I have a basket, which is saved in the session and after the successfully created order this session / basket is completely cleared. And the basket has a method that returns the amount of goods and after clearing the basket of goods it returns `0`, which is logical, but I need to save the amount to a variable and pass this variable to the second method, which accepts the customer’s order ID, without changing the url, that is, I want so that in url there was only an identifier, but not an identifier + amount. I need to pass an argument from one method to another. Now I will show what I mean.

**views.py**

```
def order_create(request):
  cart = Cart(request) # session
  sum = cart.get_total_price() # the value of the sum is saved to the variable
  if request.method == 'POST':
      form = OrderCreateForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
         # data storage
         cart.clear_session() # clear the session after a successful order
      return redirect(reverse('order:order_success', kwargs={'pk':order.id})) # how to pass here also the `sum` variable
  else:
       return HttpResponse('y')
```

Pass order ID to order_success method

```
def order_success(request, pk, sum):
   print(sum)
   # data processing and data page return
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^order/(?P<pk>[0-9A-Fa-f-]+)$', views.order_success, name='order_success'),
```

How can you pass a value to a method without releasing the sum value in the url to everyone's contemplation. I ask for help from you!

Comment: Your two views handle separate requests, i.e. your `order_create` view sends a response to the user's browser which then sends a request for the `order_success` view. So you cannot "pass" an argument from method to method as you say. You have to save the sum somewhere (which I assume you do when saving the form/order) and fetch it again in your `order_success` view.

Comment: Alternatively you can save it in the user's session (`request.session['sum'] = sum`) and then retrieve it again in `order_success` with `request.session['sum']`.

Comment: @dirkgroten, thank you for your advice